# Get method name from path and request method - Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm writing a middleware for my Rails applications, and I'm doing some sort of historic of actions made by the users. From the request I can get the path and the method, so I thought that should be a way to map it and get the method called by that combination.

This is the middleware so far:

```
class AccountabilityMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    dup._call env
  end

  def _call(env)
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)

    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if !req.get? && req.path.starts_with?('/admin') && !req.path.starts_with?('/admin/login')
      Accountability.create!(
        user: env['warden'].user,
        url: req.path,
        method: req.request_method,
        params: req.params,
        method_name: ???????????????
        response_status: @status,
        response: @response.body,
      )
    end

    [@status, @headers, @response]
  end
end
```

For example, for a path `/admin/my_model` and method `POST`, I'd like to get `"new_admin_my_model"` -- A method already defined in the project (by ActiveAdmin)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Mapping of incoming requests to a particular controller action (method) is the Rails router's responsibility - Rack middleware stack has no idea of it. You probably could play around with the routing machinery... But the initial idea itself is quite controversial imho: the particular controllers/methods are implementation details that might change many-many times during the app lifecycle (for the very same public API contract), so your `Accountability` records might (and most probably will) contain information that is useless at minimum (and might be absolutely misleading in the worst case).

Comment: I've thought of the changes, and that was one more reason to try it. For example, if the POST for a specific routes change its name or its functionality, the table would have the previous name and the date of the request so we would know it happened in an older version of the code. Any idea of how to achieve this? Point is I want to know Who triggered each controller method

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Konstantin that this is probably best left to the Rails router.

However, using info in a string to construct a new string isn't too hard if you know all the options.

Just spitballing, this is un-tested

```rb
method_constructor = '_admin_'

# just an example of some logic
pre =
  case req.request_method
  when POST
    'new'
  when GET
    'show'
  # and so on
  end

method_constructor.prepend pre

method_constructor.append req.path.gsub('/admin/', '')

# method_constructor will now be a string like 'new_admin_my_model'
```

This logic obviously needs to be more complex than just considering the `request_method` in isolation, you'll probably need to map things out the same way [Rails does](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).